# Youtube JSON fail

Tags: json, youtube-api

When I try to get JSON from this URL :

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/user/favorites?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1
```

I get this message :

```
{"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":403,"message":"Not allowed.","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"ServiceForbiddenException","internalReason":"Not allowed."}]}}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for help.

Update :

I already made all video as public. This is my real URL :
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/favorites?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1`.

I also try to get uploads channel, and it's only return an empty array.
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1`

Comment: Did you also typed the url "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc" in your web browser as the web address ? Doing so should show the response with the feed result.

Answer (score 1):

I think in that URL, where it says `user`, you need to replace that with a valid YouTube username.

Comment: I just make an example `user` as username.

Answer (score 1):

The error message (code":403,"message":"Not allowed."), means that the "user" is keeping his favorites list PRIVATE. It only works if the "user" makes it PUBLIC or if you also provide an access_token.

Note, that API V2 is deprecated.

Update 9-25-2013:
When i try your url "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/favorites" the result is: "Not allowed.". This means you have made this list private. You can set this list to PUBLIC by unchecking the check-box "Make this list private" in https://www.youtube.com/my_favorites (when you are signed-in to YouTube). And assuming you have some videos in your Favorites list which are also public.

When i try your url "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/uploads?v=2&alt=json" i do get a result. the response shows that there are 56 videos in that list. If you get an empty list there could be something wrong in your code.

Comment: I already made all video as public. This is my real URL :
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/favorites?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1`.

I also try to get uploads channel, and it's only return an empty array.
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ptiundiksha/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1`

Comment: I think I just need time to wait. Because I'm not doing anything but youtube jSON is working right now.

Anyway, thanks so much for your help :)